# How to convert Image files to CSV with label

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Test folder has folders named from 0 to 9. The 0-9 folders include respective handwritten digit images. I want to convert the images to a single test.csv file such that the first column gives the label of the digit (i.e 0-9) and the rest columns give the pixel value if image.

I created the csv but the first column for the label is being shown empty.

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import imageio
import glob
root = './test' 

# go through each directory in the root folder given above
for directory, subdirectories, files in os.walk(root):
    # go through each file in that directory
    for file in files:  
        # read the image file and extract its pixels
        im = imread(os.path.join(directory,file))
        value = im.flatten()
        value = np.hstack((directory[8:],value))
        df = pd.DataFrame(value).T
        df = df.sample(frac=1) # shuffle the dataset
        with open('test.csv', 'a') as dataset: 
            df.to_csv(dataset, header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: you should add pandas, imageio and numpy tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import imageio
import glob
import pathlib
v = []
for i,files in enumerate(pathlib.Path('./Train').glob('*/**/*.png')):
    im = imread(files.as_posix())
    value = im.flatten()
    value = np.hstack((int(files.parent.name),value))
    v.append(value)
df = pd.DataFrame(v)
df = df.sample(frac=1)
df.to_csv('train.csv',header=False,index=False)
```

This is how I corrected my code.